# Remove and Change some texts of a URL in an HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I remove and change some texts of a URL in an HTML using Javascript.

For example, I have this instagram photo in my HTML.

```
<img src="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/10611172_606838796104009_200732638_s.jpg">
```

Then I want it to be linked automatically (via javascript) to it's larger image preview here:
http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/10611172_606838796104009_200732638_n.jpg

Notice that the _s was changed to _n and the folder /t51.2885-15 was removed in the URL.

So basically I just want a javascript to remove the /t51.2885-15 and replace the _s with _n.

I think this can be achieved using javascript but I don't know why. Can this be easily written with a few lines of code? Or do you have other suggestions other than writing a javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, in plain-JavaScript (as your question doesn't imply your use of any libraries, such as [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) for example):

```
// wrapped the function as an 'Immediately-Invoked Function Expression' (IIFE)
// so that it'll be called automatically, when encountered:
(function () {
// gets all the images on the page:
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img'),
// creates an '<a>' element:
        link = document.createElement('a'),
// creates a variable (for later use, within the 'forEach()'):
        newLink;

// uses 'Array.prototype.forEach()' to iterate over the images:
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {

    // checks that 'instagram.com' is in the 'src' of the current image:
        if (img.src.indexOf('instagram.com') > -1) {
            // if it is, we clone the created-'a' element:
            newLink = link.cloneNode();

            // set the 'href' of the '<a>' to the 'src' of the image,
            // but first we replace '_s' with '_n', and
            // any sequence of characters starting with a '/' followed by
            // 't51' continuing with alphanumeric characters (a-z, 0-9,
            // case-insensitive) periods ('.') or hyphens ('-') with an
            // empty string (removing that sequence from the 'src'):
            newLink.href = img.src.replace(/(_s)|(\/t51[\w\d.-]+)/g,function (match){
                return match === '_s' ? '_n' : '';
            });

            // insert the '<a>' element before the image:
            img.parentNode.insertBefore(newLink,img);
            // move the image into the '<a>':
            newLink.appendChild(img);
        }
    });
})();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tbdn2pm1/1/).

This should be placed immediately before the closing `</body>` tag; in order to run after the DOM has been constructed.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.clonenode).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: So nice. This also works handsomely. Gonna implement it @ http://sunnies.jehzlau.net/ I think this is perfect. :D

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Comment: Nice! I just implemented it and it works great. I just replced the URL to cdninstagram.com. Thank you so much! You're a true Javascript Guru. Btw, what does the [\w\d.-]+ in your regex mean? I see that the t51 is for the folder that starts with t51, but I don't get what [\w\d.-]+ mean. And how did you come up with it. If there are digits after a folder name, I'll just add [\w\d.-]+? So that I'll know what to do next if I need to rewrite a URL using plain javascript alone. :)

Comment: You can see it live http://sunnies.jehzlau.net. I'm so so happy. Now I just need to put it in a lightbox. Yay! :D

Comment: [\w\d.-]+ means (a-z, 0-9)?

Comment: Btw, I want to implement this lightbox in your script: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/. How can I add the data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption" in the image link in your script. As I can't add it directly in the code, because the javascript you wrote automatically created an href for images from instagram.com. O__O

Comment: I think I should create a new question for this. :D

Comment: nevermind my questions. I was able to figure it out. Thanksssssss again! You've been a very very very great help. :D

Comment: Those questions are precisely why I tend to add the list of references below my answers; read through those. Though, perhaps I wasn't clear about my using a regular expression. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yep I just read the comments you added and now I slightly understand what you wrote. But still, I can't come up with that on my own. Hopefully soon I'll learn to code javascript from scratch just like you did. :D Thanks again for the help. :)

Comment: It's okay and, for what it's worth, *using*, and *implementing*,  JavaScript isn't that hard (I did that, more or less, by accident): *understanding* JavaScript is the hard part. And I'm still not there, yet.

Comment: Yeah. But you're too gooood. I wish I could have an accident like that. :D hahaha. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 0):

You just have to place this img tag under "a" tag like:

```
 <a href="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/10611172_606838796104009_200732638_n.jpg"><img src="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/10611172_606838796104009_200732638_s.jpg"></a>
```

this will create hyperlink over image and when you click on image it will navigate to the lager image.

And if you do not want to navigate to next page you will  have to register click event over image and onclick event you will change the 'src' attribute of image.(Since i am in hurry right now if you need sample code of this i can provide you later.)

jsfidle for next page navigation  is : http://jsfiddle.net/0bsrgtym/

And you can also see  the sample code for my second suggestion (it uses jquery) from here:http://jsfiddle.net/e7bLuro5/

Comment: The URLs are generated dynamically by an extension in Magento. I can't just implemement this one because what I have is not just a static HTML. As if there's a new image in Instagram that is fetched directly by the extension I'm using, the images should update automatically, that's why I'm thinking of a javascript implementation. Anyway, thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

v1 wrapped the image element , as read Question initially as requirement to link from smaller image to larger image. Re-read Question ; appear requirement for smaller image `src` to be replaced with larger image `src` ?

Try

v2

```
$("img[src*=cdninstagram]")
.attr("src", function(i, o) {
  return o.replace(/(t+\d+\.+\d+\-+\d+\/)/, "")
         .replace(/_s/, "_n")
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/gwdusxuh/

Comment: Whoa! This implementation is also great. I think I can use this one. Btw, the page is: http://sunnies.jehzlau.net/.

As you can see, there's an instagram box below, on those images are fetched automatically from instagram. I think I just need to do some tweaks to your script so that I can add a href per image. :D Thanks again! :D